# Reference request: Newton-Kantorovich hypothesis for polynomials of integral coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, polynomials, numerical-methods

Kantorovich's theorem states that the Newton method for finding the
roots of a nonlinear function is guaranteed to converge if a
parameter $h$, determined by the values of the function and its
derivative at the starting point and its Lipschitz constant, is less
than some fixed value.

My question is about articles and books on how this $h$ is
bounded for familiar functions.  I am particularly interested in
polynomials with integral coefficients, and how $h$ is bounded in
terms of their coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [personal home page of  Prof. Ferreira](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/p/3371-publications) for articles of Newton-Kantorovich method and variants:

Expository Article: [Kantorovich's s theorem on  Newton's method.](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_KantNewt_2012_1209.5704v1.pdf?1351508016)

I believe that your search will be successful for polynomials that satisfy the condition Nesterov-Nemirovskii ie if the polynomial is a [function of self-concordant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-concordant_function). Below articles that relate the Kantorovich’s theorem and self-concordant functions.

- [Kantorovich s majorants principle for Newton s method.](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/up/328/o/MajPrinc_2009.pdf?1332017892)
- [A robust Kantorovich’s theorem on the inexact Newton
  method with relative residual error tolerance.](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_RobusInexNew_2012.pdf?1334711614%20)
- [Local convergence of Newton’s method in Banach space from the
  viewpoint of the majorant principle](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_LocNew_2009.pdf?1332017782)
- [Local convergence analysis of inexact Newton-like methods under majorant condition](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3903.pdf)
- [Local convergence analysis of the Gauss–Newton method
  under a majorant condition](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_LocGausNew_2011.pdf?1332016936)
- [Local convergence analysis of inexact Gauss–Newton like methods
  under majorant condition](http://orizon.mat.ufg.br/uploads/328/original_LocGauNew_2012.pdf?1332014971)

Comment: Thank you.  What I really wanted to see was the particular application of the Newton method to polynomials of integral coefficients.  (Please let me know if one of these articles contains the application, just in case I overlooked it.)